# Convert QString to const void*

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, qt5, qstring

I am developing a software with Qt5 for sending sms on my mac. I am using a UMTS Stick and the library `"unistd.h"` to write to the file descriptor. The problem is that I do not know how to use the function ["ssize_t write(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count)"](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write). In Qt5 I have a `QTextEdit` and I would like to pass the text inside as parameter to the function `write`.

I get no errors with the following code but it does not work. Is there a mistake?

```
QString smsText = ui->smsTextField->toPlainText();

std::string utf8_text = smsText.toUtf8().constData();
const void * a = utf8_text.c_str();

write(fd, &a, sizeof(a));
```

Comment: The fact that you pass the C++ compiler checks doesn't mean that the result will make sense ! "unistd.h" in particular is very primitive and doesn't check its arguments. `void*` _literally_ can be anything. You can pass it Unicode in any encoding, and it will happily accept it. Whether that makes a readable SMS is pure luck.

Comment: What is the type of your file descriptor ? Depending on its type you may or may not use a QT class to access the same functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
write(fd, utf8_text.c_str(), utf8_text.size());
```

`&a` contains the address of your `void` pointer. Besides, `sizeof(a)`, when `a` is a pointer, will always return the same length (probably 4 or 8 bytes depending on your architecture).

Comment: As a further improvement, there's no need of building a std::string out of it, as that's *another* heap allocation and copy. Just store what you already have: `const QByteArray utf8String = string.toUtf8(); write(fd, utf8String.constData(), utf8String.size());`

Answer (score 3):

There are two, related problems. You're using `&a` and `sizeof(a)` as the parameters. This bascially means you're writing the address stored in the pointer `a` into the stream.

You should instead pass the data *at* that address, with the size given by the string's length:

```
write(fd, a, utf8_text.size());
```